# command prompt installing C++ package on windows 8 myfitter

Tags: c++, windows, installation, package, prompt

I am trying to install the package "myfitter" in windows. The documentation has instructions for linux, I guess? The instructions say to run:

```
cd myfitter-2.0

./ configure --prefix=myprefix

make 

make install
```

It says "myprefix" is a directory I have access to, so I guess where I want to install it? I'm using mingw64 with codeblocks, so would I put it into mingw, codeblocks, or the codeblocks project? And does anyone know what the proper way would be to install in windows? I tried looking for command prompt commands but it doesn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: if you have a makefile and you need to make it work in Windows (and make sure it will), you can use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)